# Add elements of an array to a specific index of each array within an array of arrays

Tags: ruby

I have an array of arrays that serves as a table of data, and am trying to add an extra array as though adding an extra column to the table.

For simplicity, suppose the first array is `a`

```
a = [["a", "b", "c"], ["e", "f", "g"], ["i", "j", "k"]]
```

and the second array is `b`

```
b = ["d", "h", "l"]
```

the desired output is:

```
c = [["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["e", "f", "g", "h"], ["i", "j", "k", "l"]]
```

I have tried using `+` and some attempts at using `map` but cannot get it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can zip them together which will create array elements like `[["a", "b", "c"], "d"]` and then just flatten each element.

```
a.zip(b).map(&:flatten)
#=> [["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["e", "f", "g", "h"], ["i", "j", "k", "l"]]
```

Answer improved as per Cary's comment. I think he's done Ruby stuff before.

Comment: Preference noted, and answer amended, @CarySwoveland

Comment: I was not clear. I meant I preferred your answer over the others that had been given at that time.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answers. Can I add a `!` somewhere to assign the output as the new `a`?

Comment: Interestingly  @CarySwoveland first answer did that (mutate the `a` array).  It was `a.zip(b).map{|arr, elem| arr << elem}` And he changed it because he thought changing `a` was undesirable. A bang(`!`) in my method at `map` or `flatten` would only mutate the zip output or the major elements in the zip output, so can't be used for what you want.  You could always do simple assignment... `a = a.zip(b).map(&:flatten)` which would make the intent clear but `a` would contain a new object. I would be inclined to go for assignment, otherwise, use Cary's solution to mutate the original `a` object.

Answer (score 4):

```
a.zip(b).map { |arr,e| arr + [e] }
  #=> [["a", "b", "c", "d"],
  #    ["e", "f", "g", "h"],
  #    ["i", "j", "k", "l"]]
```

The intermediate calculation is as follows.

```
a.zip(b)
  #=> [[["a", "b", "c"], "d"],
  #    [["e", "f", "g"], "h"],
  #    [["i", "j", "k"], "l"]]
```

See [Array#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-zip).

Comment: Thanks, @Steve. I got that result because my original answer was incorrect.

Comment: Your original answer was correct as it returned the right result.  However it mutated `a` in the process.

Comment: @Steve, yes. I didn't want it to mutate `a` or `b`, so regarded it as incorrect. (Dancing with words.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#each_with_index` combined with `#map` to iterate over the array `a` and append respective elements of array `b`

```
> a.each_with_index.map{|e, i| e | [b[i]] }
=> [["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["e", "f", "g", "h"], ["i", "j", "k", "l"]]
```